# Getting target.name from a button with an image content returns null or empty string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using an event dispatcher to dispatch the button click event. The buttons looks like this:

`<Button name="editOrderBtn"><img src="icons/edit.svg"/></Button>`

But when I try to access its name using

```
const handleRowClick = (e) => {
  e.detail.target.getAttribute("name") || e.detail.target.name
}
```

It either returns `""` or returns null. But if I use the button without the svg like so:

`<Button name="editOrderBtn">Edit</Button>`

then I can get the name attribute like: `editOrderBtn`

Any clue?

Comment: e.target.closest('button')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

target is going to be what is clicked, so you need to find the parent button. You can do that with [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.closest('button').name);
  });
});
```

```html
<button name="aaa">Test 1</button>
<button name="bbb"><span>Test 2</span></button>
```

OR the correct solution is you use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which is what the event handler was attached to and not what element was actually clicked.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<button name="aaa">Test 1</button>
<button name="bbb"><span>Test 2</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.getAttribute()` method returns an empty string or `null` when the specified attribute isn't found on the element.

In your case, when it returns an empty string, `event.target` is not the button but some other element nested within the button that doesn't have a `name` attribute on it. You will have to click on the `button` element, to make sure that `event.target` is the `button`, to get its `name` attribute value.

You can solve the problem by using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method. This will work because `.closest()` method traverses the element and its ancestor elements until it finds the node that matches the selector that is passed to this method as an argument. If not matching element is found, it returns `null`.

```
e.detail.target.closest('button').getAttribute("name")
```

or you can pass an attribute selector

```
e.detail.target.closest('button[name="editOrderBtn"]').getAttribute("name")
```